# Strange dynamic marking 'fmo' in Clementi sonata

Tags: notation, dynamics

I have come across an odd dynamics marking '***f***<sup>*mo*</sup>' whilst studying at a copy of Clementi's Sonata in Bb major, Op. 24, No. 2, dated c1790. The below image shows mvmt. 1, mm. 90–94.

[image: mm. 90–94 from Clementi Sonata in Bb Op. 24, No. 2, mvmt. 1]

Newer editions have the marking as ***ff***, although ***ff*** is used elsewhere in this score, what is intended with this particular marking?

Comment: On the page containing the "fmo", are there any other "f" symbols after the "fmo"?

Comment: @Aaron Yes there are, there are "f" and "ff" symbols on this same page. The score seems to use "fmo" and "pmo" interchangeably with "ff" and "pp".

Comment: Is this edition available online?  The only 18th century editions I see on IMSLP are of #1 (and they use a different _z_ in _fz_ as well as a square bracket instead of a curly brace to group the staves into systems).  In particular I'd be interested to see some examples of _ff_ in this edition.

Comment: Just to confirm, there are "f"s that occur on that page *after* the "fmo"?

Comment: This edition can be viewed online at the british library's website, and yes there are f's and ff's that occur after this marking in the score.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

It's an abbreviation for "fortissimo" – i.e., ***f***ortissi***mo***.

It (f<sup>mo</sup>) can be found as an abbreviation for *fortissimo* in *A Dictionary of Terms Used in Music* 3rd ed., by Thomas Valentine (London: S. Chappell, 1833), page 66 ([Google Books](https://books.google.com/books?id=LiZhAAAAcAAJ&pg=PT2#v=onepage&q&f=false)).

[image: Image from p. 66 of "A Dictionary of Terms..." showing "fmo" for "fortissimo"]

Why the Clementi score uses the abbreviations inconsistently  (since a later comment mentions that *ff* also appears on the same page of the score) is not clear.

Comment: I've seen some older scores that use *fmo* as a substitute for *fff*, so it might be they expect *fmo* to be even louder than *ff*?

Comment: Inconsistent dynamic markings is nothing special in older music (printed or manuscript). In [one J.S: Bach work that I edited](https://imslp.org/wiki/Ouverture_nach_Franz%C3%B6sischer_Art%2C_BWV_831_(Bach%2C_Johann_Sebastian)) *piano*, *p.* and *pia* were used interchangeably in the manuscript, and similarly *f.*, *forte* and *fort.*